# where is the terminal to test my workflow

Tags: c#

I'm using a template from studio and would like to test the flow. In the tutorial the lecture enters the terminal to write some code and then tests the function. Where can I find this terminal?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/how-to-run-a-workflow

Comment: Please add some more details. At least which studio do you use?

Comment: I think someone have probably left it near the staplers again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. I first click API explorer found on the left under the heading RUNTIME. I enter the drop down box and select studio then cycle down to "Create an Execution" enter the information and click request.